# Django add/edit form not returning initial/default value set while initialisation

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have view which I use for both adding and editing a modelform. Edit form works fine but while loading the add form, the initial values which I had set through Python code is not showing.

Views.py(1):

```
def tracker_edit(request, track_id=None, template_name='posts/tracker_edit.html'):
    if track_id is not None:
        track = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=track_id)
    else:
        track = Post()
    tracker = CreateArticle(request.POST or None, instance=track)
    if request.POST and tracker.is_valid():
        tracker.save()
        redirect_url = reverse('posts:tracker_list')
        return redirect(redirect_url)

    return render(request, template_name, {
        'tracker': tracker
    })
```

Forms.py:

```
    Day_Of_Week=(('Weekday','Weekday'),('Weekend','Weekend'))
    weekno = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

    if weekno<5:
        x = ("Weekday")
    else:
        x = ("Weekend")

    Day_Of_Week = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Day_Of_Week, widget=forms.RadioSelect, initial=x)
```

For example, from the forms.py you can see I'm expecting the radio button to be auto selected as weekday or weekend. But none is selected. Im confused, am I doing anything wrong with get/put? Any fix for the above will be appreciated..

Comment: your choices tuple and form field have the same name, first change that to different names, I am talking about `Day_Of_Week` I would prefer making the tuple name to `CHOICES`

Comment: Do it in the view like mentioned here https://djangobook.com/tying-forms-views/#setting-initial-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came around this by adding the python code to produce initial values in models.py instead of forms.py.

`models.py`

```
weekno = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
    if weekno < 5:
        x = ("Weekday")
    else:
        x = ("Weekend")
    Day_Of_Week = models.TextField(null=False, db_column='dayofweek', default=x)
```